# How to use Swagger with DTOs shared between a Nest.js API and a SPA?

Tags: swagger, nestjs, dto, documentation-generation, nestjs-swagger

I have a project with a Nest.js API and an Angular SPA. The DTOs used by the SPA to communicate with the API are in a separate project called Models and I'm using it as a dependency. In that way, I only need to change the DTO in one place, and can reuse them in both projects.

I've been trying to document my API with Swagger using `@nestjs/swagger`. This lib requires me to use decorators in my DTOs if I want their attributes to be shown in Swagger.

When I do that, everything works as expected in my API, but the Angular SPA breaks because it doesn't has the `@nestjs/swagger` dependency. Even after installing it as dependency for the app, it still requires me to install `@nestjs/common`, `express`, `mime`, `send`, etc. and I shouldn't install all of those backend related dependencies to my app just for the sake of documentation.

Do you guys have any idea how to overcome this issue or other tips about documentation generation for APIs with Nest.js?

Comment: Did you find any solution for it?

Comment: @UdleiNati unfortunately not yet :(

Answer (score 0):

The `@nestjs/swagger` exposes the `SwaggerModule` which can be used for our problem. Use the following code examples:

```
import { NestFactory } from "@nestjs/common"
import { DocumentBuilder, SwaggerModule } from "@nestjs/swagger"
import { writeFileSync } from "fs"

const app = await NestFactory.create(YourAppModule)
const documentBuilder = new DocumentBuilder()
.setTitle("My API")
.setDescription("OpenAPI documentation for my API")
const openApiDocument = SwaggerModule.createDocument(app, documentBuilder.build())
const openApiJsonDocument = JSON.stringify(openApiDocument, undefined, 2)
writeFileSync("openApi.json", openApiJsonDocument, { encoding: "utf-8" })
```

After having the `openApi.json`, you can make use of the `@openapitools/openapi-generator-cli` npm package to generate an API client in your desired programming language as well as frontend framework.